# Combine multiple SQL fields into 1 output row

Tags: sql, mysql

Having a SQL table like

UserID |Attribute | Value
1      |Username  | Marius
1      |Password  | Fubar

I want to create an output like:

1 | Marius | Fubar

Maybe I'm just too tired to see it, doesn't sound too complicated, but I just can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use self joins, ie. :

```
select u1.userid, u1.value, u2.value 
from yourtable u1
inner join yourtable u2 on u2.userid=u1.userid
where u1.attribute='Username' and u2.attribute='Password';
```

Comment: Very short and working solution in my scenario, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Would something like...

```
SELECT userID,
       GROUP_CONCAT (Value SEPARATOR '|')
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY UserID;
```

be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

**One column per result:**

If you try to combine multiple Attributes with the same UserID it would be something like this:

Short query (one UserID):

```
declare @concattedtext varchar(1000)

SELECT @concattedtext=coalesce(@concattedtext + '|', '') + Value
FROM #users WHERE UserID=1

SELECT @concattedtext
```

RESULT with your example data:

```
1 | Marius | Fubar
```

Full query (all UserID's)

```
-- Your source table
CREATE Table #users (UserID int, Attribute varchar(50), Value varchar(50))
-- some entries
INSERT into #users (UserID, Attribute, Value)
VALUES (1, 'Test1', 'attr1')
INSERT into #users (UserID, Attribute, Value)
VALUES (1, 'Test2', 'attr2')
INSERT into #users (UserID, Attribute, Value)
VALUES (1, 'Test3', 'attr3')
INSERT into #users (UserID, Attribute, Value)
VALUES (2, 'Test4', 'attr4')

-- ids table variable (for distinct UserID's)
DECLARE @ids TABLE
(
 rownum int IDENTITY (1, 1) Primary key NOT NULL,
 UserID int
)

-- Output table variable
DECLARE @out TABLE
(
 rownum int IDENTITY (1, 1) Primary key NOT NULL,
 UserID int,
 ConcatText varchar(1000)
)

-- get distinct id's
INSERT INTO @ids(UserID)
SELECT DISTINCT(UserID) FROM #users

-- Foreach vars
declare @RowCnt int
declare @MaxRows int
select @RowCnt = 1
select @MaxRows=count(*) from @ids

-- UserID
declare @id int
declare @concattedtext varchar(1000)

-- process each id
while @RowCnt <= @MaxRows
begin
 SET @id = 0

 SELECT @id=UserID
 FROM @ids WHERE rownum=@RowCnt

 SET @concattedtext = CONVERT(nvarchar(50), @id)
 FROM @ids WHERE rownum=@RowCnt

 SELECT @concattedtext=coalesce(@concattedtext + '|', '') + Value
 FROM #users WHERE UserID=@id

 INSERT INTO @out(UserID, ConcatText)
 VALUES (@id, @concattedtext)

 -- next UserID
 Select @RowCnt = @RowCnt + 1
end

SELECT * FROM @out

DROP TABLE #users
```

Result:

```
rownum|UserID|ConcatTex
1     | 1    |1|attr1|attr2|attr3
2     | 2    |2|attr4
DROP TABLE #users
```

You might need a sort field to get your parameters in your requested order.

**Multiple columns**

Your data needs to have an equal count of attributes if you like to get a table with multiple columns. And you still need to take care about the ordering.

In this case a hardcoded query with a group by would be your choice.

Comment: sorry, those downslashes are just meant to seperate columns. my problem is that i want fields from 2 or more lines to be returned in one row

Comment: But this is what you need to do - just exchange the downslash with whatever you want. You didn't mention this fact before.

Comment: So - you need to get a two column table or a multicolumn table? The second one is hard. You need to do multiple queries to accomplish that. E.G. sql while and grouped by UserId. Please edit your question to reflect this details.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your data that way, you will need to do a crosstab query and pivot your rows into columns. If you are using Microsoft SQL Server, check out "crosstab query" and the pivot operator in Books Online.